# Instant App link in SMS does not work

Tags: android-instant-apps

I have created an Instant App that works perfectly when I click its link in an email. When I send the same link in an SMS and click it, the default-url is displayed. I am using AS3.2 Canary 9. Has anyone seen the same thing?

Comment: I was able to get mine to open from SMS. Does your SMS direct it to a browser other than Chrome?

Comment: @TWL Thanks! That is encouraging. I am suspecting the problem is in the way pathPattern is working with AIA. Another might be how clients (email or SMS) hand off to it.    I am testing with an HTML "parent" page with an embedded URL that should execute an instantapp. I can send that direct link in an email received by Gmail and the instantapp runs OK. If I send the parent URL then click the embedded link to instantapp, it is treated as such but then crashes.

Comment: Oh, so you're saying that your IA will still open from SMS, but then it will crash? You have the logs surrounding that crash?

Comment: @TWL Then to test SMS and browser, I send SMS w/ the direct instant link. Clicking it displays the default-app set (not the instantapp). If I send the parent URL, clicking it in the SMS displays the page properly. But the direct link in that page also displays the default-url set in the feature manifest instead of the instantapp.    Chrome is the default browser, but I think the problem occurs earlier.    The URL that should trigger instantapp display is being treated differently when coming from email and SMS clients.

Comment: @TWL When I test a device cabled to AS, the URL I am using works fine. It is when I send a real message to a device untethered (i.e., using the Play Store internal test) that the problems occur. So there are no logs. Is there a way I can get them?

Comment: You can still keep your deviced tethered while you do this live test, logcat should still record all the events, just keep it unfiltered.

Comment: @TWL Thanks. I will try that. Just to be clear, however. I am less concerned about the crash in the email case. The critical concern is having a URL sent in an SMS trigger instantapp.

Comment: Of course. I think it's something wrong with your SMS client/app, it handles the URL differently than Gmail. You can also try your URL in Google Docs. What kind of device do you have?

Comment: @TWL Test device is Samsung S7. Logcat shows:  [INFO:CONSOLE(4)] "Error parsing a meta element's content: ';' is not a valid key-value pair separator. Please use ',' instead.", source: https://quixr.com/?Flight=58dsvnf (4)
2018-04-22 14:51:22.085 6177-6177/? I/chromium: [INFO:CONSOLE(33)] "Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token )", source: https://quixr.com/?Flight=58dsvnf (33)    I can't tell where the offending ";" is coming from - certainly not the URL - nor the ")"

Comment: @TWL Test in Google Docs: Direct link to instantapp worked perfectly. Link to "parent" page with the direct link embedded was not opened in browser as a standard HTML page, but was treated as an AIA link. That goes back to the pathPattern problem of having links on a domain all be treated as instantapp links if the pathPattern is "/.*"   The conclusion is that Gmail is handling the instantapp URL properly.    Beyond the Logcat clues I gave you, what can I do to track down what is happening with the URL handoff from the SMS client?

Comment: Ok, aside from your instant app, if your installed-app was installed, does the link from the SMS redirect to your app? How about from Gmail/Docs? They should behave exactly the same. Check your logs when you tap on the link from SMS. Or, can you provide a URL for me to test?

Comment: @TWL On the run, more tomorrow. Installed app is NOT installed - some problem w/ my Install button in the instantapp. The links work perfectly in Google Docs. Also if the SMS default is Google Messages. Samsung native SMS client seems to be at least one problem.  <br/>Will check logs tomorrow. How can I give you a link to test?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/169628/discussion-between-twl-and-jaw).

Answer (score 0):

This depends of the message app of your phone. Sometimes the message app have an internal web view to manage the urls. In this case the link is directly open in web browser.

If the link is open in the default browser, you should go in this browser app settings and check the links already set as manage by this browser. Or clear the cache of the browser. if it s still not working, go in :

Settings -> Google -> Instant app, then disable an enable it again.

if it s still not working, make it sure by rebooting the device.